# Question and answer with the most upvotes

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes, up-votes

On Mi Yodeya, what is the question with

- The most upvotes

Similarly, what is the answer with

- The most upvotes

Answer (score 4):

You can find all questions sorted by votes at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion and all answers sorted by votes at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer

Currently the top voted question is [Implications of Samoa skipping a Friday](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12760/759) and the top voted answer is at [Rejecting others' friend requests on Facebook](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14756/759)

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful.